# Projective variety $Y\subset P^n,\dim(Y)\geq 1$ and hypersurface $H\subset P^n$. $H\cap Y\neq\emptyset$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

This is a problem of Hartshorne 1.3.7(b). I have solved in Hartshorne's hint way and I am trying something else.

If $Y\subset P^n$ is projective of dimension $\geq 1$, for any hypersurface $H\subset P^n$, $H\cap Y\neq\emptyset$.

My plan is lifting the variety through cone map to $A^{n+1}$. I want to show $\dim(H\cap Y)\geq 1$. This is done in the similarly way to show any two hypersurface of $P^n$ has non-trivial intersection for $n\geq 2$. So I will denote cone over $Y$ as $Y$ and cone over $H$ as $H$.

Denote coordinate ring of $A^{n+1}$ as $R$. Since $I(H)\subset R$ is generated by single irreducible element, I will consider $(I(H)+I(Y))/I(H)\subset R/I(H)$.

It suffices to show its height is $<n$. I know I can reduce to the case $1\leq \dim(Y)<n-1$ which in turn says $2<\mathrm{ht}(I(Y))\leq n-1$. I wish to show $\mathrm{ht}(P)<n-1$, $P$ minimal over $I(Y)+I(H)$. However, it is not clear I can adjust the chain of $I(Y)$ easily as I do not know whether $I(H)$ is contained in some maximal ideal containing $I(Y)$.

Any hint will suffice.

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble following your last paragraph. Do you want to show that the height of $I(H)+I(Y)$ is at most $n$? If so, your claim follows from Krull’s height theorem since $I(H)$ is principal.

Comment: @Youngsu I do not know what is the height of $I(H)+I(Y)$. It is not a prime. You have to check there is a prime minimal above it of height less than n. I do not know which version of krull principal thm you are referring to. Please tell me the reference.

Comment: Would you clarify if you are referring to $\le$ or $\lneq$ in your post and comment?

Comment: @Youngsu Showing the hypersurface intersection is always non-trivial, I can always use krull principal ideal theorem as I knew it will be generated by 2 element. For this one, I only know $1\leq dim(Y)\leq n-1$ and I do not know how many generators are there. The twisted cubic is a good example. I do not have to reprove the dimension $n-1$ case anymore. I pulled $Y$ back to affine case $A^{n+1}$ by cone map. I need to show height of minimal prime over $I(Y)$ in affine case has height less than n-1.

Comment: I am still confused by your phase “less than $n-1$“. Do you mean $\lneq n-1$ or $\le n-1$? In either case, I believe that you are trying to show if an ideal $I$ is of height $s$, then ht $(I,h) \le s+1$, where $h \in R$. Am I correct?

Comment: In $A^{n+1}$, two variety has intersection in projective sense requiring dimension$\geq 1$. So $ht$ of the irreducible component of intersection must be $\leq n$. $dim_{P^n}(Y)\geq n-1$ is trivial. I do not need that proof. If you are confused by what I said, then you can show if $dim_{P^n}(Y)\geq 1$, then intersection between $Y$ and any hypersurface is non-empty in $P^n$ by pulling it back to affine instead.

Comment: $ht(I,h)\leq s+1$ is not guaranteed as there is no clear reason why a chain of $I$ and $h$ can be modified jointly together to form a chain of length$\leq s+1$. Under the assumption that the intersection non-trivial, I can adjust the chain.

Comment: One way to see ht $(I,h) \le s+1$ is the following. Let $P$ be a (homogeneous) prime ideal which is minimal over $I$ and of height $s$. In $R/P$ the ideal generated by the image of $h$ is of ht $\le 1$. So there exists a (homogeneous) prime ideal $Q$ in $R$ such whose image in $R/P$ is of height at most 1 and contains $h$. The only question that remains is that why ht $Q \le s +1$ in $R$. In general, this is false. But $R$ is universally cetenary, and this implies that ht $Q \le s+1$.

Comment: @Youngsu It suffices to show $R$ is universally catenary. From which I should see $ht(Q)\leq s+1$. I will check matsumura commutative ring theory book. Thanks.